# Losing access token

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

Sometimes my Facebook object goes from something like this:

```
[fb] => Facebook Object
    (
      [appId:protected] => 350348105029704
      [appSecret:protected] => 9e84****************************
      [user:protected] => 
      [signedRequest:protected] => 
      [state:protected] => 
      [accessToken:protected] => AAACQm6g*****************
      [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
    )
```

into something like this:

```
[fb] => Facebook Object
    (
      [appId:protected] => 350348105029704
      [appSecret:protected] => 9e84****************************
      [user:protected] => 
      [signedRequest:protected] => 
      [state:protected] => 
      [accessToken:protected] => 350348105029704|9e84****************************
      [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
    )
```

appSecret is masked of course and so is the access token. But as you can see, in the second object it's not a valid access token, but one that is made out of the appId|appSecret.

It happens randomly and I can't seem to catch it while it happens, what can be the cause of that?

Comment: Also just mentioning this is a Facebook connect website and not a Facebook canvas app.

Comment: Where does the access token come from? is that the result of a call to getAccessToken() in the PHP SDK? Are you doing any other verification that the user is logged in?

Comment: It may come from 2 sources:
1. The getAccessToken() in the PHP SDK.
2. Being sent as a GET parameter after SSO login from a native app (Android/iOS).
I am doing verification yes, but I am getting this problem every once in a while, it's pretty random